# ANOVA on percentage data

Tags: anova, percentage, two-way

I am confused about when I can and/or cannot run an ANOVA on percentage data. MY situation is as follows:

I have two separate treatment groups (T1 and T2). Each of these treatment groups receives 1 of 3 drugs (D0, D3, D30) only once. My DV is muscle activity (continuous data). Only one muscle response is recorded. 3 consistent pre-drug baseline measurements and 3 consistent post-drug measurements are taken.

I take the mean of the pre and post to give single values, and then calculate the post-drug as a % of pre drug for each subject, and then compare mean % for each treatment/drug group

The raw data are generally not normally distributed (though one group out of six comes out as normal but only just)

The problem I have is that pre-drug values are **quite variable** and so I think it's better to look at the **proportion change** *(if indeed that it the correct thing to do?)*. Previously I have just expressed the post-drug values as a percentage of the pre-drug *(not percentage difference)*, and then compared the mean percentages of the various different groups with a **two-way ANOVA**. *(nb. the percentage data are normally distributed according to shapiro-wilks test)*

So for example, pre-drug value = 500, post drug = 100, thus the % baseline is 0.2 (20%).

Is this a valid comparison?? I am less interested in absolute size of pre or post-drug values. It seems quite logical to me but my stats knowledge is pretty basic.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation & your data? Do you have repeated measures? Are the data normally distributed within each group x time combination?

Comment: Do you have a before & after measure for each participant? How many muscles are measured on each participant? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more and more strongly emerging consensus that you *cannot* analyze percentage data with ANOVA. Some of the two latest references are Jaeger (2008) and Dixon (2008) the abstract of which I post below.

Jaeger, T. F. (2008). [Categorical data analysis: Away from ANOVAs (transformation or not) and towards logit mixed models.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2613284/) Journal of Memory and Language, 59(4), 434–446. http://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2007.11.007

> This paper identifies several serious problems with the widespread use
>   of ANOVAs for the analysis of categorical outcome variables such as
>   forced-choice variables, question-answer accuracy, choice in
>   production (e.g. in syntactic priming research), et cetera. I show
>   that even after applying the arcsine-square-root transformation to
>   proportional data, ANOVA can yield spurious results. I discuss
>   conceptual issues underlying these problems and alternatives provided
>   by modern statistics. Specifically, I introduce ordinary logit models
>   (i.e. logistic regression), which are well-suited to analyze
>   categorical data and offer many advantages over ANOVA. Unfortunately,
>   ordinary logit models do not include random effect modeling. To
>   address this issue, I describe mixed logit models (Generalized Linear
>   Mixed Models for binomially distributed outcomes, Breslow and Clayton
>   [Breslow, N. E. & Clayton, D. G. (1993). Approximate inference in
>   generalized linear mixed models. Journal of the American Statistical
>   Society 88(421), 9–25]), which combine the advantages of ordinary
>   logit models with the ability to account for random subject and item
>   effects in one step of analysis. Throughout the paper, I use a
>   psycholinguistic data set to compare the different statistical
>   methods.

Dixon, P. (2008). [Models of accuracy in repeated-measures designs.](http://www.psych.ualberta.ca/~pdixon/Home/resources/Dixon2008.pdf) Journal of Memory and Language, 59(4), 447–456. http://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2007.11.004

> Accuracy is often analyzed using analysis of variance techniques in
>   which the data are assumed to be normally distributed. However,
>   accuracy data are discrete rather than continuous, and proportion
>   correct are constrained to the range 0–1. Monte Carlo simulations are
>   presented illustrating how this can lead to distortions in the pattern
>   of means. An alternative is to analyze accuracy using logistic
>   regression. In this technique, the log odds (or logit) of proportion
>   correct is modeled as a linear function of the factors in the design.
>   In effect, accuracy is rescaled in terms of a logit
>   “response-strength” measure. Because the logit scale is unbounded, it
>   is not susceptible to the same scaling artifacts as proportion
>   correct. However, repeated-measures designs are not readily handled in
>   standard logistic regression. I consider two approaches to analyzing
>   such designs: conditional logistic regression, in which a Rasch model
>   is assumed for the data, and generalized linear mixed-effect analysis,
>   in which quasi-maximum likelihood techniques are used to estimate
>   model parameters. Monte Carlo simulations demonstrate that the latter
>   is superior when effect size varies over subjects.

Comment: These papers both seem to be about summarizing categorical data as percentages. The question here is about continuous data tabulated as percent change from a control measurement.